How to set the API login page URL in Nuxt 3 Sidebase settings?
How to set the API login page URL in Nuxt 3 Sidebase settings (@sidebase/nuxt-auth)?
By default, it's redirecting to myapi.com/login, I would like to redirect to myapi.com/admin/login instead.
My API is set with Laravel 10 and Passport.
server/api/auth/[...].ts:
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from "#auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

const { passport } = useRuntimeConfig(); //get the values from the runtimeConfig
const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  secret: "my-superb-secret",
  pages: {
    // Change the default behavior to use `/login` as the path for the sign-in page
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider.default({
      clientId: runtimeConfig.public.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: runtimeConfig.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code",
        },
      },
    }),
    {
      id: "laravelpassport", //ID is only used for the callback URL
      name: "Passport", // name is used for the login button
      type: "oauth", // connexion type
      version: "2.0", // oauth version
      authorization: {
        url: `${passport.baseUrl}/oauth/authorize`,
        params: {
          scope: "*",
        },
      },
      token: {
        url: `${passport.baseUrl}/oauth/token`,
      },
      clientId: passport.clientId, // the client Id
      clientSecret: passport.clientSecret, // the client secret
      userinfo: {
        url: `${passport.baseUrl}/api/v1/me`,
      },
      profile: (profile) => {
        return profile;
      },
      idToken: false,
    },
  ],
});

